# Why is MariaDB 10 refusing to use my index on a date field?

Tags: index, performance, mariadb, mysql-5.6, query-performance

I have the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `bets` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_mp` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `coin` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `game_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `group_turn_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `direction` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bet_amount` double NOT NULL,
  `multiplier` double NOT NULL,
  `target` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `result` double NOT NULL,
  `profit` double NOT NULL,
  `win` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `seed` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `bets_time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1189677 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

You'll note that there is a primary key as well as a secondary index on the 'time' field. Mysteriously though, the following query refuses to use the bets_time index:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(1) AS num_bets, SUM(bet_amount) AS total_wager FROM bets WHERE `time` > (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

yields the following:

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | bets  | ALL  | bets_time     | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1132313 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

As you can see it sees bet_time as a possible index, but does not use it. Any ideas as to why this might be happening? I guess I could use FORCE INDEX on the query, but I'd rather avoid hardcoding such query logic into the SQL and prefer an 'proper' solution.

Thanks a lot for any ideas.

Comment: You can use FORCE INDEX to see how "rows" estimation changes - my first guess is that either statistics are bit off or data so bad that optimizer decides index is not worth it - usual heuristics is that if query has to read more than (IIRC) 20% of rows, then reading index and then rows in "random" order is worse than reading everything sequentially.

Comment: Check real numbers with "SELECT count(1), `time` FROM betw GROUP BY `time` > (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)" to see actual distribution. ANALYZE TABLE can get statistict up to date, but usually thats not needed (InnoDB computes them sort of semi-automatically by "index-dives")

Comment: Analyze table makes no difference, but forcing the index just about halves query time, so I've opted for this solution for now.

Comment: That was not meant as a solution! But as means to compare EXPLAINs and estimates with and without the index. When you get those numbers you will know more about what's the possible reason.

Comment: Try adding an index on `(time, bet_amount)`.

Answer (score 1):

The optimizer seems to think that your index is not selective enough. I think that you can do one or more of the following things:

- `ANALYZE TABLE bets`;
- `ALTER TABLE bets ADD INDEX bets_time_amount (time, amount); /* this is a covering index */`
- add a `FORCE INDEX` to your `SELECT`

Comment: You should only use `FORCE INDEX` as a last resort. +1 for your answer anyway.

Comment: I agree... but sometimes it is necessary.